# Key error when dividind one row by another in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to perform some calculations across a complex data set and struggling to get the right approach. In simple terms, what I would like to do is divide a value in one row, by a value in another row. A sample of what I mean is as follows;

|  | Column A | Values | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | row 1 | 5 | abc |
| 1 | row 2 | 10 | def |
| 2 | row 3 | 15 | ghi |

The output that I desire, is to divide row1 by row2, giving me 0.5, or 50% and place this data in a new row (row 4). I essentially want to ignore, Column B and row 3 in this scenario. I still want their data in the output, but they are not involved in the calculation. Output should look like this, or similar.

|  | Column A | Values | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | row 1 | 5 | abc |
| 1 | row 2 | 10 | def |
| 2 | row 3 | 15 | ghi |
| 3 | row 4 | 0.5 | NaN |

This is a simplified version, as I'll have a large number of rows and columns in reality, however the concept is the same. I want to tell pandas which two rows to divide, multiply etc and put it into a new row.

This should be fairly simple, using the following code that I found;

```
df['row4']=df.loc[row 1]/df.loc[row.2]
```

However this returns a key error on Row 1

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-c216003d88c4> in <module>
----> 1 df['row4']=df.loc['row 1']/df.loc['row 2']

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    893 
    894             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 895             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
    896 
    897     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: Tuple):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1122         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1123         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1124         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1125 
   1126     def _get_slice_axis(self, slice_obj: slice, axis: int):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
   1071     def _get_label(self, label, axis: int):
   1072         # GH#5667 this will fail if the label is not present in the axis.
-> 1073         return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)
   1074 
   1075     def _handle_lowerdim_multi_index_axis0(self, tup: Tuple):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3737                 raise TypeError(f"Expected label or tuple of labels, got {key}") from e
   3738         else:
-> 3739             loc = index.get_loc(key)
   3740 
   3741             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    352                 except ValueError as err:
    353                     raise KeyError(key) from err
--> 354             raise KeyError(key)
    355         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    356 

KeyError: 'row 1'
```

Any help is very welcome!

Comment: Did you tried to use the column A as your index, and then perform your division? Maybe can be a good approach for your problem...

Comment: None of the index values in `df['row4']=df.loc[row 1]/df.loc[row.2]` are going to work with your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def append_value(index1, index2, shape):
    return {
        "Column A": f"row {shape}",
        "Values": df["Values"].iloc[index1]/df["Values"].iloc[index2]
    }


df.append(append_value(0, 1, df.shape[0]), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, it’s almost there but the label name of that column shows as NaN. Is there a way to label the column? E.g row 4 in example above.